# how to find the substring in dictionary keys using ICollection or IList

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Dictionary<string, string> aStr = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        aStr.Add("FONT_BOLD_4DSTR_CORRECT", "VALUE");

        ICollection<string> strCol = aStr.Keys;

        if (strCol.Contains("FONT_BOLD_4DSTR"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hurrah string found");
        }

        int count = 0;
        foreach(string a in strCol)
        {
            if (a.Contains("FONT_BOLD_4DSTR"))
            {
                count++;
            }

        }

        if(aStr.Keys.ToList().Contains("FONT_BOLD_4DSTR"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("list found the bold data");
        }


        Console.WriteLine("the number of string count is {0}", count);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Need to find the substring in dictionary keys. If i do string.contains, able to find the substring.

If keys are stored in collection or converted to list, not able to find the substring. Is there any way to find substring using lists or collection contains.

Comment: The List<> method 'contains' looks for an exact match while the string methods 'contains' looks for a partial match.  You can use a Linq expressions to get the results : var match = strCol.Select((x,i) => new {Key = x, count = i}).Where(x => x.Key.Contains("FONT_BOLD_4DSTR")).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a little LINQ:

```
bool hasKey = aStr.Keys.Any(k => k.Contains("FONT_BOLD_4DSTR"));
if (hasKey) {
    // found the bold data
}
```

If you need the count too, rearrange your logic a bit:

```
int matchCount = aStr.Keys.Count(k => k.Contains("FONT_BOLD_4DSTR"));

bool hasKey = matchCount > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use LinQ:

```
ICollection<string> strCol = aStr.Keys;

if (strCol.Any( a => a.Contains("FONT_BOLD_4DSTR") ))
{
    Console.WriteLine("hurrah string found");
}
```